# Modelling time series described by nonlinear system of equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm modeling a dynamic system described by three nonlinear second order differential equations. Luckily, I have the closed form solution for the system which is a set of four coupled nonlinear equations (the `sigm` is self-defined function for sigmoid):

```
y = Yprev(1); y0 = Yprev(2); y1 = Yprev(3); y2 = Yprev(4);

for (i=1:N)
  y0 = aa*sigm(y1-y0,parsigm);
  y1 = aa*(p+c2*sigm(c1*y0,parsigm));
  y2 = bb*c4*sigm(c3*y0,parsigm);
  y = aa*p + aa*c2*sigm(aa*c1*sigm(y,parsigm),parsigm) -bb*c4*sigm(aa*c3*sigm(y,parsigm),parsigm);
end
```

`Yperv` is a vector of values of different `y`s of the previous iteration, In fact, I didn't put them in the for loop since I'm planning to call the model at different codes. At the end of the day, I need the simulated the time series produced by the model.

There are at least two problems here:

1. The values of `y0` come from the previous iteration while the others are from the same iteration. In other words, at iteration `i`, `y0` is calculated based on `y1` and `y0` of iteration `i-1`, but in the next line, `y1` is calculated with `y0` of iteration `i`. Personally, that doesn't look good to me.
2. As said earlier, I need to reuse the model and start it with arbitrary values, and the bookkeeping of the previous values and passing them to the function do not to be the best practice.

Is there a nice way of implementing this?

Comment: Does updating `y0` last work for you?That way you use all values from the same iteration. I don'd understand your second point, it needs a [mcve]

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ah I forgot to add the initialization
`y = Yprev(1);
y0 = Yprev(2);
y1 = Yprev(3);
y2 = Yprev(4);`
Then there is the for loop:
`for (i=1:N) {...} end`
The first problem is, at iteration i, y0 is calculated based on `y1` and `y0` of i-1, but in the next line, `y1` is calculated with `y0` of iteration i. This is the problem I thins needs to be addressed.
For the second issue, since I need to reuse this system many times, I tried putting it in a function that can be called in a for loop in a 2nd script, but it then needs to be instantiated before the loop in the 2nd script.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with any relevant information and full code.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the remarks @AnderBiguri.

Comment: Just put the computation of `y0` last in the loop to solve your first problem. For the second one, I still dont get it. Just return the values? make a fucntion?

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri, that helped for both. It's hard for me to rephrase the second issue but I now know how to handle it. Thanks again.